# notifyDataSetChanged Error inside AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I got an Error while loading many Items in my `ListView` using a `CustomAdapter` with `BaseAdapter`.

I'm using the `CustomAdapter` in `onPostExecute` method.

```
class setProjectsFilesNamesMap extends  AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        //Fülle die Maps mit Daten
        for (int position = 0; position < projectFileNamesMap.size(); position++) {
            String filename = projectFileNamesMap.get(position);
            setJobMap(filename);
            setProjectMap(filename);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        CustomAdapterProjects adapter = new CustomAdapterProjects(ProjectsList.context, projectMap, jobMap);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

When starting another `Activity` and press the Back Button this Error comes and the App crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class CustomAdapter.CustomAdapterProjects)]
```

**EDIT:**
setMaps:

```
public void setMaps(String filename) {

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(readProjectsFromFile(filename));
    if (!(doc == null)) {
        NodeList project = doc.getElementsByTagName(project);

        for (int i = 0; i < project.getLength(); i++) {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            Element e = (Element) project.item(i);

            map.put(project_uuid, parser.getAttribute(e, project_uuid));

            map.put(project_company, parser.getValue(e, project_company));
            map.put(project_company_image, parser.getValue(e, project_company_image));
            map.put(project_company_street, parser.getValue(e, project_company_street));
            map.put(project_company_zip, parser.getValue(e, project_company_zip));
            map.put(project_company_city, parser.getValue(e, project_company_city));
            //map.put(project_company_country, parser.getValue(e, project_company_country));
            projectMap.add(map);
        }
        NodeList job = doc.getElementsByTagName(job);
        for (int i = 0; i < job.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            Element e = (Element) job.item(i);

            map.put(job_uuid, parser.getAttribute(e, job_uuid));

            map.put(job_subject, parser.getValue(e, job_subject));
            map.put(job_description, parser.getValue(e, job_description));
            //map.put(job_typ, parser.getValue(e, job_typ));
            map.put(job_deadline, parser.getValue(e, job_deadline));
            //map.put(job_task_count_all, parser.getValue(e, job_task_count_all));
            //map.put(job_task_count_open, parser.getValue(e, job_task_count_open));
            jobMap.add(map);
        }
    }
}
```

getDOMElement:

```
    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {

    Document doc;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));

        doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error Parser: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error SAX: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error IO: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Where do I have to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` and what does that method?

Comment: Do not add items in your list/map in bg thread. Do it that in `onPostExecute`..

Comment: So the `doInBackground`method will only return true?

Comment: `notifydatasetchanged()` is used when your underlying dataset is changed and you need to tell the listview to update itself.

Comment: What are you intent to do in the first place ?

Comment: i just want to fill the maps with data. It takes to long in the UI-Thread so i thought i would do that in an AsyncTask.

Comment: Please post the full class (not just the inner setProjectsFilesNamesMap  AsyncTask)

Comment: it's about 1000 rows of code... what exaclty are you looking for?

Comment: setJobMap(filename);
            setProjectMap(filename); what there functions doing ?

Comment: setJobMap(filename); setProjectMap(filename);

Comment: added the function. i merged both methods to one method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doInBackground()` (as the name implies) runs on a background thread. The data that is generated in that thread (specifically the HashMaps added to projectMap and jobMap) are not available in another thread unless you post a runner etc. with the data. What AsyncTask does (among other things) behind the scenes is to pass the data from the background thread to the UI thread. It does this from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()`.

What you can do is to modify the AsyncTask so that `doInBackground()` returns the data you need (instead of returning null) and then use it as a parameter in `onPostExecute()`. For example:

```
class setProjectsFilesNamesMap extends  AsyncTask<Void,Void,HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> > >{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> doInBackground(Void...voids) {
        //Fülle die Maps mit Daten
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> data = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        for (int position = 0; position < projectFileNamesMap.size(); position++) {
            String filename = projectFileNamesMap.get(position);
            ArrayList <String> jobMap = setJobMap(filename);
            ArrayList <String> projectMap = setProjectMap(filename);
            data.add("jobMap", jobMap);
            data.add("projectMap", projectMap):
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap <String, ArrayList<String>> data){
        CustomAdapterProjects adapter = new CustomAdapterProjects(ProjectsList.context, data.get("projectMap"), data.get("jobMap"));
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Of course this would mean that you would need to alter setJobMap and setProjectMap to return the maps instead of just setting them.

Comment: I have set the map like `public static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> projectMap = new ArrayList<>();` to access them all over the class...

Comment: I know, but that won't help for a background task. Put it this way, it's almost as if doInBackground is in another class.

Comment: what about performance? is this way faster than i do until yet?

Comment: It _may_ be a bit faster if you do your own threading. But either way, the point of the AsyncTask (or Thread if you decide to go that route) isn't speed. Rather, it means that while your data is loading, the ui is still responsive to the user. he can still swipe and touch. See [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) on android developers to help you out.

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck.